# Запуск программ по расписанию через waitable timer C#

Tags: c#

Я пишу курсовую запуск программ по расписанию на C#, тип проекта Windows Forms. Преподаватель сказал реализовать через waitable timer. Вот мой код :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string date, time, datenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), timenow = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), way;
    // MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    // MessageBox.Show(timenow);
    Process p = new Process();
    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Master\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Cursovaya OS 1\Cursovaya OS 1\bin\Debug\datetime"))
    {
        while (!fs.EndOfStream)
        {
             // Читаем строку из файла во временную переменную.
             date = fs.ReadLine();

             //time = fs.ReadLine();
             way = fs.ReadLine();
             p.StartInfo.FileName = way;

             DateTime utc;
             utc=Convert.ToDateTime(date);
             // MessageBox.Show(utc.ToString());
             long duetime = utc.ToFileTime();
             handle = CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr.Zero, true, "WaitableTimer");
             SetWaitableTimer(handle, ref duetime, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, true);
             uint INFINITE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
             int ret = WaitForSingleObject(handle, INFINITE);
             p.Start(); 
        }
```

Но процесс не запускается. Формат файла где находится дата и время, а также путь к файлу:

```
08.03.2017 9:20
D:\Des1.txt
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в проблеме.

Comment: Господи, какой ужас. WaitFirSingleObject? А почему не обыкновенный `await Task.Delay()`?

Comment: @VladD Это же курсовая, преподаватели зачастую требуют делать так, как было принято у них лет 8-10 назад. Это норма в нынешнем образовании.

Comment: @V.Birkos: Ну это как бы да. Но в таком случае имеет смысл выучить как правильно делать, набраться смелости и поправить преподавателя. Преподаватель тоже человек, он может и ошибаться.

Comment: @VladD Не каждый преподаватель признает свою неправоту, даже после долгих разбирательств с весомыми аргументами и доказательствами(Бывают крайне неадекватные, либо мне так везло просто). Так что в некоторых случаях лучше сделать как он хочет, сдать ему все и забыть про него. Но, конечно же, каждый случай индивидуален) Если преподаватель адекватный по общению, можно хорошо подготовиться и попытаться поправить его, согласен.

Comment: @VladD А кто решил, что это неправильно. Я не раз тут на so видел задачи вида "решить это без использования того то". Обычная практика искусственных ограничений. Вообще то полезная практика, которая развивает способность решать задачи нестандартно.

Comment: @vitidev: Ну да, и все эти задачи — искусственные, учебные. Если нельзя пользоваться классом X, ну так можно взять исходник этого класса и переназвать его Y, делов-то. Правильные, хорошие, полезные для людей ограничения — это не ограничения типа «не пользоваться исключениями», а скорее типа «без дополнительных аллокаций». Первое ограничение — бессмысленное, придуманное обычно теми, кто не может смириться с реальностями языка и хочет заставить писать на C# как на K&R C. Второе имеет смысл и может быть даже полезно.